# Teenage star lost in a city

Tags: identify-this-movie

Date: Maybe 5-10 years old.

Country of origin: Don't know, seen it with hungarian dubbing,

It's a teen-romance movie. The boy is a star singer who while on tour, somehow misses his trailer and is left behind in a foreign city. The girl starts helping him, becomes his guide, she even lets him stay in her family's house, without the consent of her parents.
The girl is an amateur photographer and she delivers pizza (?) after school to gather money for college and she's being ridiculed for this by her peers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, it was [Be Somebody](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5512872/) (2016).

> Pop superstar Jordan Jaye has a big dream - he just wants to live like a regular teenager. When he's chased down by some excited female fans, he finds a perfect hideout and a reluctant new friend from a small town, high-school art student, Emily Lowe. Despite being from different worlds, they soon discover they have way more in common than they ever imagined. Over the course of several days, the two embark on an unexpected journey of friendship, first love and self-discovery -- proving that maybe opposites really do attract.

Answer (score 2):

It can be [StarStruck](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1579247/)

> Jessica Olsen was expecting a normal trip to California with her family to visit her grandma. However, she agrees to join her older sister to find the famous pop star, Christopher Wilde.

From part of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starstruck_(2010_film)) synonyms:

> Fed up with waiting, Jessica leaves the car in search for Sara and meets Christopher when he hits her in the head while opening a door. Eager to avoid being caught by the paparazzi, Christopher takes Jessica to a hospital to be examined, then brings her to his house so that he can make an appearance for the film director (Hero). He then brings Jessica home, and Jessica allows him to stay in her grandmother's garage for the night when he learns the paparazzi have followed him.

Film trailer :

I did see this film but forgot most of it except garage scene. Not sure about pizza delivery or photography part.